# css media styles does not work after browser window was refreshed

Tags: css

```
#wrap {
    background: white;
    margin: 20px 15px;
    padding: 10px;  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #wrap {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }
}
```

These styles seems to be working if I open new browser window and try to resize it. But if I refresh windows once then `@media` does not work. Then I need to close the browser and open it againe to open the same site to re-enable `@media` styles. What is going on here?

Comment: The media rule is for devices smaller than 600px wide. if your screen is bigger; the effect won't kick-in until you resize it so that the browser window  is smaller than that. Post your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #wrap {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }
}
```

I find it works best when you have the word "ONLY" in the media query. Heres an example of the bootstrap media queries.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries

If that doesnt work try a hard refresh to clear your browser cache.

Comment: A hard refresh helped to fix that issue.